# Get MatterID from iManage/Worksite doc within MS Word

Tags: ms-word, imanage, worksite-sdk

I'm trying to retrieve the MatterId entered by the user when they saved the document in MS Word.

My code is running from with a MS Word Add-in.

I'm starting with the following code:

```
dynamic service = doc.Application.COMAddIns.Find(Addin).Object;
dynamic document = service.GetDocumentFromPath(doc.FullName);
return document.MatterId;
```

Can anyone assist with this? and also point me towards the documentation. i'm finding the various versions a bit confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Here's the code in case anyone else struggles with the same thing. Not sure why I couldn't reference the assemblies..

```
//var service = (iManageExtensibility)doc.Application.COMAddIns.Find(Addin).Object;
//var document = (NRTDocument)service.GetDocumentFromPath(doc.FullName);
dynamic service = doc.Application.COMAddIns.Find(Addin).Object;
dynamic document = service.GetDocumentFromPath(doc.FullName);
foreach (dynamic attribute in document.CustomAttributes)
    if (attribute.Type == 26) // AttributeID.nrCustom2
        return attribute.Name;
```

Comment: Just to clarify the answer, the matter ID is exposed as a custom property on the IManDocument class as opposed to an explicitly named property like MatterId. In this instance, Custom2. You should be able to use the enum imProfileAttributeID.imProfileCustom2 to refer to this attribute in document.CustomAttributes.

Comment: More information can be found in the WorkSite COM Developers Reference Guide (8.5, English).pdf file which is provided as part of the IManage SDK. This is a commercial SDK that you need to licence so you should speak to your IManage partner about getting access to it.